# Website works with machine name but not with localhost

Tags: asp.net, proxy, web-config

I have a website and after creating a virtual directory and using local IIS I see that the website displays the page when I use
      https:///Home/Signin.aspx. 
but it is not working when I use https://localhost/Home/Signin.aspx .

I tried adding the following in the web.config

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
</defaultProxy>
<settings>
    <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
</settings>
```

Any input on this will be helpful.

Note : It is also using a Certificate used by the company. and I'm using Windows 8 as teh operating system.

Comment: And what does your host header configuration look like in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was : 
1. Edit the host file located in

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in notepad++ as an administrator.

Add a line
    localhost

2. Go to IIS 
   Select Default website. In the right hand side, Click on Bindings
   Select Type : Https . Make sure the host name is blank. (In my case it was having the machine name as the Host name and SSL certificate contained the name of the company's certificate.